# Как поймать исключение?

Tags: php, исключения

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    try{
        include APP. '/' . $class . '.php';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Выброшено исключение: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
});
```

В переменной `$class` имя класса, но иногда поступает знчение не существующего имени класса. Все мои попытки отловить ошибку именно используя try/catch не удались. require вместо include пробовал - сразу всё в Fatal error выпадает.

Как поймать ошибку в Exception $e всё же и корректно завершить скрипт без Notice и Warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include` не выбрасывает исключений, а возвращает `FALSE` в случае ошибки. [см. пример №4](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php)

Т.е. использовать надо так:

```
$result = include APP. '/' . $class . '.php';
if($result === false){
    echo "Не удалось подключить файл";
}
```

Обратите внимание, что также будет выдана ошибка уровня WARNING.

Но лучше всего сначала проверять, существует ли файл.

```
if(is_file(APP. '/' . $class . '.php')){
    include APP. '/' . $class . '.php';
} else {
    echo "Такого файла нет";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как узнать какие функции выбрасывают исключения а какие нет?

Comment: @fosh4455 Из документации вестимо

Comment: `Но лучше всего сначала проверять, существует ли файл` - так длиннее, много кода

Comment: @fosh4455 Это называется "экономия на спичках". Хороший код - это такой код, который работает корректно и не порождает непредсказуемых побочных эффектов, а не тот, который короче. Функция `include` не предназначена для проверки существования файла и в будущих редакциях PHP вполне может начать выбрасывать `fatal error` например.

Comment: да, всё же убедили